# Javascript load pair of images randomly

Tags: javascript

On page load, I'd like two random images to appear in separate divs that always load as a pair, i.e. two dogs, two cats, or two horses; but never a cat and a dog, a horse and a cat, etc.

This is what I've come to so far...

```js
var dog1 = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/SfLV8hD7zX4/maxresdefault.jpg";
var dog2 = "http://weknowyourdreams.com/images/dog/dog-06.jpg";
var dogpics=[dog1,dog2];

function imgs_rand(){
  switch(Math.random()*3|0){
      case 0:
          return dogpics;
          break;
      case 1:
          return console.log("case 1");
          break;
      case 2:
          return console.log("case 2");
          break;
  }
}
console.log(imgs_rand()[0,1]);
document.getElementById('img1').src=imgs_rand()[0];
document.getElementById('img2').src=imgs_rand()[1];
```

It's not working, for obvious reasons.  Please help me realize why these reasons are obvious.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You just want to randomly pick an image from `dogpics`?

Comment: No, I want a specific pair of images to appear on page load. Two particular images.

Comment: well ... clearly in case 1 and case 2 you aren't returning an array of images like in case 0

Comment: As in dog1 and dog2 are static, unchanging images and will always appear together on the page.

Comment: but case 1 and 2 return undefined, so, your code will break except in case 0

Comment: So how are the other pair(s) of images looking? Like are they in another array like dogpics2 ? or is it a multidimensional array then?

Comment: When you use Math.floor(Math.random()*10%3) 10÷3 will give you a decimal number and array only work and use integer numbers, so in your switch it never will be 1 or 2, that is the obvious reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not generate a multidmensional array. Then let random just return a random number where the biggest number is the array length. So you can change your array and always get a pair (two images) from that array...

```js
var dog1 = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/SfLV8hD7zX4/maxresdefault.jpg";
var dog2 = "http://weknowyourdreams.com/images/dog/dog-06.jpg";
var dogpics=[dog1,dog2];

var yourPics = [
  dogpics,
  [  // sports
    'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1/',
    'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/2/'
  ],
  [  // nature
    'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/nature/1/',
    'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/nature/2/'
  
  ]
];

function get_random_number(array){
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
}
var rand_number = get_random_number(yourPics);
console.log(rand_number);
document.getElementById('img1').src = yourPics[rand_number][0];
document.getElementById('img2').src = yourPics[rand_number][1];
```

```css
img {
    max-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<img id="img1" >
<img id="img2" >
```

Comment: This is very clever!  It's not what I was asking but it's a cleaner, more elegant way to accomplish the same goal.  Thank you!

Comment: @BrianBurke glad it helped! Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

You had a few of problems:

- `console.log()` returns `undefined`, so `return console.log()` also returns `undefined`.
- you called `imgs_rand()` a separate time for each image, so it is likely that they have a different pair -- you need to call it once and then reference its return value twice for the array indexes.

Thy this:

```js
var dog1 = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/SfLV8hD7zX4/maxresdefault.jpg";
var dog2 = "http://weknowyourdreams.com/images/dog/dog-06.jpg";
var dogpics = [dog1, dog2];
var cat1 = "https://www.petfinder.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/cat-black-superstitious-fcs-cat-myths-162286659.jpg";
var cat2 = "http://www.petmd.com/sites/default/files/scared-kitten-shutterstock_191443322.jpg";
var catpics = [cat1, cat2];
var horse1 = "http://www.horsechannel.com/images/horse-news-article-images/chestnut-horse-autumn_1000.jpg";
var horse2 = "https://www.purinamills.com/2.purinamills.com/media/Images/MasterBrand/Lifestages/horse-special-needs.png?ext=.png";
var horsepics = [horse1, horse2];

function imgs_rand(){
  switch(Math.floor(Math.random()*10%3)){
      case 0:
          return dogpics;
          break;
      case 1:
          return catpics;
          break;
      case 2:
          return horsepics;
          break;
  }
}
var images = imgs_rand();
console.log(images);
document.getElementById('img1').src=(images[0]);
document.getElementById('img2').src=(images[1]);
```

```css
img {
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<img id="img1"/>
<img id="img2"/>
```

DISCLAIMER: Images copyright their respective owners.

Comment: This totally works, thank you so much!  I knew I was on the wrong track but I didn't even think about calling `imgs_rand()` twice.  And adding `Math.floor` just made everything work.  Awesome.